# Wordpress site Search results are slow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In my Wordpress site, web page takes long time to load the results in browser.
This is my link **https://myedubuddy.com/Pgfilter/filters**.
I have used Divi theme builder for this site. When you search in "Dynamic search" box and click on any result, you will see box where Part Numbers are shown and every part number has anchor tag and on clicking it gets redirected to product page that shows all information about that part number,
but problem is that while redirecting to product page it takes long time that irritates users.
I have deleted all plugins and used wp-rocket plugin for caching pages but still it takes long time to load page in browser! Can anyone suggest different approach?

Comment: It seem's your hosting service is slow...

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved ,its all because of URL rewriting in function.php.